# GPUImage Different Preview to Output

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, gpuimage

For the first time when using a different GPUImage filter I am seeing strange performance where GPUImage is showing a fairly big difference between the live preview and outputted photo.

I am currently experiencing this with GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter as follows;

[image: difference]

On the left hand side I have a screenshot of the device screen and on the right, the outputted photo. It seems significantly reduce the thickness and sharpness of the detected lines outputting a very different picture.

I have tried having SmoothlyScaleOutput on and off, but as I am not currently scaling the image this should not be effecting it.

The filter is set up like so;

```
        filterforphoto = [[GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter alloc] init];
        [(GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter *)filterforphoto setShouldSmoothlyScaleOutput:NO];
        [stillCamera addTarget:filterforphoto];

        [filterforphoto addTarget:primaryView];
        [stillCamera startCameraCapture];

        [(GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter *)filterforphoto setEdgeStrength:1.0];
```

And the photo is taken like so;

```
        [stillCamera capturePhotoAsImageProcessedUpToFilter:filterforphoto withCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *processedImage, NSError *error){
```

Does anyone know why GPUImage is interpreting the live camera so differently to the outputted photo? Is it simply because the preview is of a much lower quality than the final image and therefore does look different on a full resolution image?

Thanks,

(p.s. Please ignore the slightly different sizing on the left and right image, I didn't quite light them up as well as I could have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is indeed because of the different resolution between the live preview and the photo.

The way that the edge detection filters (and others like them) work is that they sample the pixels immediately on either side of the pixel currently being processed. When you provide a much higher resolution input in the form of a photo, this means that the edge detection occurs over a much smaller relative area of the image. This is also why Gaussian blurs of a certain pixel radius appear much weaker when applied to still photos vs. a live preview.

To lock the edge detection at a certain relative size, you can manually set the `texelWidth` and `texelHeight` properties on the filter. These values are 1/width and 1/height of the target image, respectively. If you set those values based on the size of the live preview, you should see a consistent edge size in the final photo. Some details may be slightly different, due to the higher resolution, but it should mostly be the same.

Comment: Thanks Brad - A saviour as always. Having tinkered with this for the evening it does everything I need it to and makes complete sense. Thanks again.

Comment: how does one get the size of the live preview? I cannot find anything online for getting that value.